# Responsive slider with full screen background

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, responsive-design

I've been trying to make a slider with full screen background in all resolutions.

here is the example:
http://www.ssplab.com/clients/Polimeks/index.html

I'm using RoyalSlider. But it just doesn't work fine and how i expected.

I looked to SuperSized slider. But it just slides through the images, i need the content too.

Answer (score 5):

i searched full-screen slider with content before some day for my project, and i succeed using below link's example:-

http://nicinabox.github.com/superslides/#5

Hope it will be usefull for you....

Answer (score 0):

You can buy this Fullscreen Image Gallery: http://www.codegrape.com/item/jquery-fullscreen-image-gallery-v2/1439